In .net MAUI 8 app how to automatically take pictures when opening camera for taking pictures and not forcing a physical or software button click
I want to create a .net maui 8 app that allows someone to point to a PC screen or some document (like what banks allow to scan a check from front and back and when the full check is in the view (bounds are withing mobile camera fully) I want to take the picture automatically and do some OCR pattern recogntition like for Driver licence or Healt Card number. I am aware of Plugin.Maui.OCR that will help me with OCR part.
How to enable taking picture automatically after some conditions are met like there is enought focus on the object that the OCR can be done successfully like what is done when a QR code is recognized. So I would like to possibly automatically take a series of pictures until a desired pattern is recognized.
Should I use "brute force" to just take pictures in some interval and do OCR and if positive outcome stop or is there a way to understand if there is enough focus to take a good picture . I would want to visualize the fact that I found that pattern and to visually while the video is still pointing to the object where is that place where the pattern is recognized and what is found. It is like what Google translate does from Camera to show what it recognized in a foreign language.
Also not to forget how to programmatically (via timer) take pictures and process them.
Thanks

You need to read the camera API docs for each platform to determine what is possible.  There is unlikely to be a simple cross platform solution

https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI Good place to start. A lot of code that will help you understand what you have to do.
